# Enable or disable html <a> options from typescript method

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components, wizard

This my html code:

```
<a href="#" id="continueId" class="btn btn-success m-btn m-btn--custom m-btn--icon" data-wizard-action="next">
      <span>
        <span (click)="onContinue()">
          continue
        </span>
        <i class="la la-arrow-right"> </i>
      </span>
    </a>
```

This onContinue() method:

```
onContinue(){
  if (!this.testForm.valid) {
    //here where I want to enable or disable data-wizard-action="next"
  }
}
```

What I want is to enable or disable data-wizard-action="next" from my Angular typescript code in "onContinue()" method. If my form is not valid, so I'll disable the click of next button else, I'll enable the click. The problem here, that the continue click is attached to the data-wizard-action="next" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***ngIf** to show or hide a html element.

```
<div *ngIf="this.testForm.valid; then continueIdWith; else continueIdWithout"></div>

<ng-template #continueIdWith">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success m-btn m-btn--custom m-btn--icon" data-wizard-action="next">
</ng-template>
<ng-template #continueIdWithout">   
        <a  href="#" class="btn btn-success m-btn m-btn--custom m-btn--icon">
</ng-template>
```

Comment: What I want is to disable/enable the click of next button by typescript:
if my form is not valid, so I'll disable the click of next button
else, I'll enable the click.

The problem here, that the continue click is attached to the data-wizard-action="next" attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Angularify" like this

```
<div .. [attr.data-wizard-action]="next">
```

and

```
  onContinue(){
    this.next=!this.next
  ...
```

Comment: what does it mean `Angularify` ?

Comment: What I want is to disable/enable the click of next button by typescript :
if my form is not valid, so I'll disable the click of next button
else, I'll enable the click.

The problem here, that the continue click is attached to the data-wizard-action="next" attribute

Comment: <a [disabled]="!testForm.valid">... should work then. or <a [disabled]="!isValid"> and in onContinue(){isValid=this.testForm.valid}

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vega
this is what I want
but, I still can not controle data-wizard-action="next"
because even with your code the test form still continue on next step

Comment: Isn't <a> tag disabled when the form is invalid? Could you complete your post with some more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

No more strict way to disable link button. I think you use css for disabling the link button conditionaly and then prevent the click of link button.

Try to use

```
<a (click)="onContinue($event)" href="javascript:void(0)" id="continueId" class="btn btn-success m-btn m-btn--custom m-btn--icon" data-wizard-action="next" [ngClass]="{'disabled-anchor': 'yourCondition'}">
    <span>
        <span>
          continue
        </span>
    <i class="la la-arrow-right"> </i>
    </span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled-anchor {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;    
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  onContinue(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (!this.testForm.valid) {
      //here where I want to enable or disable data-wizard-action="next"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think OP is asking for attribute disabled not using css

Comment: What I want is to disable/enable the click of next button by typescript:
if my form is not valid, so I'll disable the click of next button
else, I'll enable the click.

The problem here, that the continue click is attached to the data-wizard-action="next" attribute